# dot product of two 1D vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with `numpy` in `python` to calculate a vector multiplication.
I have a vector x of dimensions n x 1 and I want to calculate x*x_transpose. 
This gives me problems because `x.T` or `x.transpose()` doesn't affect a 1 dimensional vector (`numpy` represents vertical and horizontal vectors the same way).

*But how do I calculate a (n x 1) x (1 x n) vector multiplication in `numpy`?*

numpy.dot(x,x.T) gives a scalar, not a 2D matrix as I want.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ it does give a matrix

Comment: @cdhagmann Y. I noticed the dimensions

Comment: a (1xN) matrix multiplied with a (Nx1) matrix should give a scalar. But a multiplication of (Nx1) matrix with a (1xN) matrix shouldn't.

Comment: Your arrays are not 1xN or Nx1, but 1-dimensional. If you want 2-dim arrays, use 2-dim arrays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are essentially computing an [Outer Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).

You can use `np.outer`.

```
In [15]: a=[1,2,3]

In [16]: np.outer(a,a)
Out[16]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: I'll accept this later when the 10min period is over

Answer (score 6):

While `np.outer` is the simplest way to do this, I'd thought I'd just mention how you might manipulate the `(N,)` shaped array to do this:

```
In [17]: a = np.arange(4)
In [18]: np.dot(a[:,None], a[None,:])
Out[18]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])

In [19]: np.outer(a,a)
Out[19]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

Where you could alternatively replace `None` with `np.newaxis`.

Another more exotic way to do this is with [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
In [20]: np.einsum('i,j', a, a)
Out[20]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

And just for fun, some timings, which are likely going to vary based on hardware and numpy version/compilation:

Small-ish vector

```
In [36]: a = np.arange(5, dtype=np.float64)

In [37]: %timeit np.outer(a,a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 µs per loop

In [38]: %timeit np.dot(a[:,None],a[None,:])
100000 loops, best of 3: 11 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit np.einsum('i,j', a, a)
1 loops, best of 3: 11.9 µs per loop

In [40]: %timeit a[:, None] * a
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.68 µs per loop
```

And something a little larger

```
In [42]: a = np.arange(500, dtype=np.float64)

In [43]: %timeit np.outer(a,a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 605 µs per loop

In [44]: %timeit np.dot(a[:,None],a[None,:])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit np.einsum('i,j', a, a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 359 µs per loop

In [46]: %timeit a[:, None] * a
1000 loops, best of 3: 597 µs per loop
```

Comment: Don't forget `a[:,None] * a`!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an inner product then use `numpy.dot(x,x)` for outer product use `numpy.outer(x,x)`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to define the row / column vector with 2-dimensions, e.g.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)
np.dot(a.T, a)

array([[1, 2, 3],
   [2, 4, 6],
   [3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to user `numpy.matrix`

```
>>> a = np.matrix([1,2,3])
>>> a
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> a.T * a
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]])
```

Generally use of `numpy.arrays` is preferred. However, using `numpy.matrices` can be more readable for long expressions.